# Is there any OData Query for Azure DevOps Repo?

Tags: azure-devops, odata

Scenario: I am building Power BI Dashboard on my organization data in Azure DevOps.

Referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-odata-overview?view=azure-devops), we can see there are steps to create sample report on Power BI with OData query on Azure DevOps.

In the link you can see there are 3 sections, Azure Boards, Azure Pipelines and Azure Test Plans. But, I cant find any OData API for Azure Repo.

Question is there any OData API to query on Azure Repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oData set currently doesn't have access to the repo information you're looking for however you could combine it with a REST call if you're willing to work with some static sets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

If you REALLY need it as oData you could invest the time in writing your own oData service that calls down to the REST endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following organization level query to list supported values:

`https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_odata/v3.0-preview`

For example, you can list all team projects using the following query:

`https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/Projects`

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, but it seems for Repo related in the list of ```https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_odata/v3.0-preview``` is only branches. Do we have any others like Pull Request, Push, Commits?

Comment: No, you can run `https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{Project}/_odata/v3.0-preview` to check the supported values.